# How can I filter / post-process a Python-Graphene result

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python

I'm currently writing a GraphQL API with Python-Graphene.

One resolver provides a list of entries, and I'd like to do some post-processing / filtering here. However, the properties of the child entries are not resolved at this time, of course later.

What can I do? Experimented with returning a Promise and tying to its "then" method, or writing a middleware. It all gives the "unprocessed" child entries, i.e. not with resolved data. Did some research if I can find the data in some hidden data structure, but pysnooper proves that the data simply isn't computed at this time.

Please note: I'm NOT using Django in this project.
This is a minimal example of what I try to do, **please note the TODO line**.

```py
""" Test some graphene features"""

import graphene
from collections import namedtuple
from datetime import date
from json import dumps

DBUser = namedtuple('DBUser', ('name', 'year_of_birth'))

# Our, ehm, professional database ;-)
DATABASE = [
    DBUser('John', 1970),
    DBUser('Mary', 1980),
    DBUser('Sandra', 1990),
    DBUser('Michael', 2000),
]


class User(graphene.ObjectType):

    name = graphene.String()
    age = graphene.Int()

    def resolve_name(self, info):
        return self.name

    def resolve_age(self, info):
        return date.today().year - self.year_of_birth


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):

    users = graphene.List(
        User,
        min_age=graphene.Int())

    def resolve_users(self, info, min_age):
        for dbuser in DATABASE:
            # TODO: Would like to use computed "age" of User here somehow
            if dbuser.year_of_birth < 1989:
                yield dbuser


schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
query = "query { users(minAge: 30) { name age } }"
result = schema.execute(request_string=query)
print(dumps(result.to_dict()))
```

Comment: Can you include an [mcve] in your question? You're much more likely to receive help by showing your work so far. Cheers!

Comment: OK, done so.
My only idea so far is to wrap the "User" into a wrapper class, doing the computation of age by a "caching" live property. This way, I could both ask for age in resolve_users and resolve_age, with the first request doing the computation and the second one being answered from the properties' cache.
Quite a bit of overhead, I think.

Answer (score 0):

this is exactly one of the reasons why I wrote `pydantic-resolve`

to add a `post_field` method

```py
class Person(BaseModel):
    name: str

    age: int = 0
    def resolve_age(self, loader=LD(batch_person_age_loader)):
        return loader.load(self.name)

    is_adult: bool = False
    def post_is_adult(self):
        return self.age > 18
```

this `post_method` hook is called after all descendants are resolved.

https://github.com/allmonday/pydantic-resolve